# Ajax does not fill in input value and returns undefined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-8

I wanted to build dynamic dependent dropdown select option in Laravel, so when users select a product it should show the price in input value.

So here is the form:

```
<span>Product Name</span>
<select style="width:200px" class="productname" id="prod_cat_id">
      <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">--Select--</option>
      <option value="">mina</option>
      <option value="">tohfus</option>
</select>

<span>Prodict Price</span>
<input type="text" class="prod_price" value="">
```

Then within jQuery, I wrote this:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on('change','.productname',function(){
                 var prod_id = $(this).val();
                 var a = $(this).parent();
                 var op = "";
                $.ajax({
                    type:'get',
                    url:'{!! URL::to('findPrice') !!}',
                    data:{'id':prod_id},
                    dataType:'json',
                    success:function(data){
                        // console.log(data.price);
                        a.find('.prod_price').val(data.price);
                    },
                    error:function(){

                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Now when I select one of the options from the dropdown list, the price does not appear in the input with the class of `prod_price` (And no error appears in Console Log also).

And also if I uncomment `console.log(data.price)`, it shows **undefined** as result!

Here is the route that gets the price:

```
Route::get('/findPrice', [TestController::class, 'findProductName']);
```

And in the Controller:

```
public function findPrice(Request $request)
    {
        $p = Product::select('price')->where('id', $request->id)->first();
        return response()->json($p);
    }
```

And here is my `products` table :

[image]

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please try ```dd($p)``` in your controller before this line ```return response()->json($p);```, does it show any value in network tab of developer window of browser, on your ajax request?

Comment: @RamishaMukhtar I tried that but nothing is shown at the page and in the console

Comment: Tried hitting post request URL directly from browser? what does it show?

Comment: in your select class "productname", did you set the product id into value attribute on `option` tag?

Comment: check ```var prod_id = $(this).val();``` in console log, if it is empty ,try ```var prod_id = $('#prod_cat_id').find(":selected").text();``` or ```var prod_id = $('#prod_cat_id').find(":selected").val();``` instead.